# android application update without ui

Tags: android

I would like to update my application from local webserver in the background.

I use the AppInstaller example from [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q.git).

I extended the app with `class DeviceOwnerReceiver : DeviceAdminReceiver()`,
and did add device owner permission for this app in my emulator with:

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.commonsware.q.appinstaller/.DeviceOwnerReceiver`

AppInstaller works good, if I choose an apk file from the ui, but if I put this code at the end of `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/Download").path + "/app-debug.apk"
val file = File(path)
motor.install(file.toUri())
```

I get this error in Logcat:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/app-debug.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I thought, I can achieve silent install with device owner permission, but seems like, it needs something else too.

I try this in API 30 emulator.

What am I missing?